# Android beacon library background scanning causes foreground app to crash

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon, eddystone

I am trying to create an app to scan for beacons. The foreground app works fine. However, when I try to include background scanning in the app, it causes the app to crash. Basically, once the app is launched, the app asks for permissions, closes and the notification for background scanning shows up. So, every time the background service detects a beacon, it closes the app.

What I would like to do is to somehow stop the background scanning when the app comes into the foreground. I tried using

```
regionbootstrap.disable();
```

But it doesn't solve my problem.

I am using the android beacon library 2.11-beta1

```
public class whereismybag extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier, 
RangeNotifier, BeaconConsumer {
private static final String TAG = "wherebg";
private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();



    Log.d(TAG, "Background scanning started up");
    Region region = new Region("com.example.utsav.whereismybeacon", null, null, null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);

    // To detect proprietary beacons, you must add a line like below corresponding to your beacon
    // type.  Do a web search for "setBeaconLayout" to get the proper expression.
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));

    // wake up the app when any beacon is seen (you can specify specific id filers in the parameters below)


    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(5000L);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(6000L);}




private void sendNotification(String text) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Where is My bag?")
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wimbicon);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}

public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Got a didEnterRegion call");
    // This call to disable will make it so the activity below only gets launched the first time a beacon is seen (until the next time the app is launched)
    // if you want the Activity to launch every single time beacons come into view, remove this call.
    regionBootstrap.disable();
    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    }
    catch (RemoteException e) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Can't start ranging");
    }
    sendNotification("Detecting a bag! Tap to launch app.");
    regionBootstrap.disable();
    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    /*Intent intent = new Intent(whereismybag.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.startActivity(intent);*/


@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    try {
        beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
    Log.d(TAG,"I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: " + state);
}



public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Now finding beacon range");

}

public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
}}
```

The class above is started using:

```
 android:name=".whereismybag"
```

The entire manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.utsav.whereismybag">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:name=".whereismybag"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/wimbicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/wimbicon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- android:name=".whereismybag" -->

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".splashscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".scanning"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".beaconfound"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".save"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".viewsaved"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".findingbags"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".bagfound"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".setrange"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".beaconfoundlist"></activity>
</application>
```

This is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;

/*SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.utsav.whereismybag", 0);*/
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN}, 1);
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 1);
        }
    }

    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean bluetoothadmin_enabled = false;
    //checking for active location
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    try {
        bluetoothadmin_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    if (!gps_enabled && !bluetoothadmin_enabled) {
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.gps_network_not_enabled));
        dialog.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.open_location_settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
    //checking for active bluetooth
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setMessage("This device does not support Bluetooth");
        // Device does not support Bluetooth
    } else {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            // Bluetooth is not enabled
            android.app.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.bluetooth_not_enabled));
            dialog.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.open_bluetooth_settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setupbags);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    scanning.class);
            startActivity(myIntent1);
        }
    });//Start scanning
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savedbeac);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    viewsaved.class);
            startActivity(myIntent1);
        }
    });//Start scanning
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findbags);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    findingbags.class);
            startActivity(myIntent1);
        }
    });//Start scanning
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setrange);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    setrange.class);
            startActivity(myIntent1);
        }
    });//Start scanning
}}
```

Here is the log:

```
06-12 11:20:42.616 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/.wherebg: 
Background scanning started up
06-12 11:20:42.624 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag 
I/BeaconManager: BeaconManager started up on pid 26716 named 
'com.example.utsav.whereismybag' for application package 
'com.example.utsav.whereismybag'.  isMainProcess=true
06-12 11:20:42.629 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag 
D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-
23,p:24-24,d:25-25
06-12 11:20:42.635 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag 
D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-
13,i:14-19
06-12 11:20:42.790 26716-26753/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/AppTracker: 
App Event: start
06-12 11:20:42.811 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag 
W/BluetoothCrashResolver: Can't read macs from 
BluetoothCrashResolverState.txt
06-12 11:20:42.813 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag 
I/CycledLeScanner: This Android 5.0.  We are using new scanning APIs
06-12 11:20:42.815 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag 
I/BeaconService: beaconService version 2.11-beta1 is starting up on the main 
process
06-12 11:20:42.822 26716-26756/com.example.utsav.whereismybag 
I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: 
com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
06-12 11:20:42.825 26716-26756/com.example.utsav.whereismybag 
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using 
platform default
06-12 11:20:42.843 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag 
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
06-12 11:20:42.843 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag 
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
06-12 11:20:42.846 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/BeaconService: starting with intent Intent { cmp=com.example.utsav.whereismybag/org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService }
06-12 11:20:42.846 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/BeaconService: binding
06-12 11:20:42.857 26716-26754/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 853a1ff, I9c435c2712
                                                                    Build Date                       : 01/10/17
                                                                    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.04
                                                                    Local Branch                     : 
                                                                    Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                    Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                    Reconstruct Branch               : 
06-12 11:20:42.861 26716-26754/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-12 11:20:42.861 26716-26754/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
06-12 11:20:42.867 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/.wherebg: I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: 0
06-12 11:20:42.946 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/BeaconService: start monitoring received
06-12 11:20:44.166 26716-26756/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Successfully saved new distance model file
06-12 11:20:44.167 26716-26756/com.example.utsav.whereismybag W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
06-12 11:20:44.167 26716-26756/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Successfully updated distance model with latest from online database
06-12 11:20:45.799 26716-26819/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
06-12 11:20:45.860 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/BeaconService: set scan intervals received
06-12 11:20:45.991 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-12 11:20:46.021 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag V/BoostFramework: mAcquireFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquire(int,int[])
06-12 11:20:46.021 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag V/BoostFramework: mReleaseFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockRelease()
06-12 11:20:46.021 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag V/BoostFramework: mAcquireTouchFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquireTouch(android.view.MotionEvent,android.util.DisplayMetrics,int,int[])
06-12 11:20:46.021 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag V/BoostFramework: mIOPStart method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStart(int,java.lang.String)
06-12 11:20:46.021 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag V/BoostFramework: mIOPStop method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStop()
06-12 11:20:46.023 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@df677b
06-12 11:20:46.023 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@4c8b998
06-12 11:20:46.120 26716-26753/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/AppTracker: App Event: start
06-12 11:20:46.124 26716-26756/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
06-12 11:20:46.137 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/BeaconService: set scan intervals received
06-12 11:20:46.149 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/CycledLeScanner: Adjusted scanStopTime to be 885106541
06-12 11:20:46.215 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/BeaconService: set scan intervals received
06-12 11:20:46.238 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
06-12 11:20:46.314 26716-26755/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-12 11:20:46.314 26716-26755/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
06-12 11:20:46.318 26716-26755/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-12 11:20:46.327 26716-26729/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5 mClientIf=0
06-12 11:20:46.335 26716-26729/com.example.utsav.whereismybag W/Binder: Binder call failed.
                                                                    java.lang.SecurityException: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
                                                                        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.startScan(IBluetoothGatt.java:678)
                                                                        at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper.onClientRegistered(BluetoothLeScanner.java:367)
                                                                        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:56)
                                                                        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:580)
06-12 11:20:48.328 26716-26755/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-12 11:20:50.089 26716-26819/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/AppTracker: App Event: start
06-12 11:20:50.096 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/BeaconService: set scan intervals received
06-12 11:20:50.102 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/CycledLeScanner: Adjusted scanStopTime to be 885111115
06-12 11:20:50.555 26716-26755/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-12 11:20:50.560 26716-26728/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5 mClientIf=0
06-12 11:20:50.938 26716-26973/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/.wherebg: I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: 1
06-12 11:20:50.938 26716-26973/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/.wherebg: Got a didEnterRegion call
06-12 11:20:50.959 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/BeaconService: stop monitoring received

                                                                           --------- beginning of crash
06-12 11:20:50.963 26716-26973/com.example.utsav.whereismybag E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[BeaconIntentProcessor]
                                                                            Process: com.example.utsav.whereismybag, PID: 26716
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(org.altbeacon.beacon.Region)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.example.utsav.whereismybag.whereismybag.didEnterRegion(whereismybag.java:91)
                                                                                at org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor.onHandleIntent(BeaconIntentProcessor.java:99)
                                                                                at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:68)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
06-12 11:20:50.963 26716-26973/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
06-12 11:20:50.967 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/BeaconService: unbinding
06-12 11:20:50.967 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag E/BeaconService: onDestroy()
06-12 11:20:50.967 26716-26755/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-12 11:20:50.969 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/BeaconService: onDestroy called.  stopping scanning
06-12 11:20:50.980 26716-26753/com.example.utsav.whereismybag D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
06-12 11:20:50.981 26716-26716/com.example.utsav.whereismybag E/BeaconManager: Cannot contact service to set scan periods
06-12 11:20:50.984 26716-26753/com.example.utsav.whereismybag E/DeviceManagerUtil: RunningAppProcessInfo is null
06-12 11:20:50.986 26716-26973/com.example.utsav.whereismybag I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26716 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you post the log cat

Comment: I've added the logs now. @MuhammadYounas

Comment: on which version you are testing

Comment: API 25 (7.1.1)@MuhammadYounas

Comment: than you are missing the location services permission

Comment: The crash happens because the `beaconManager` instance in `whereismybag` is somehow null.  You can see this here: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(org.altbeacon.beacon.Region)' on a null object reference at com.example.utsav.whereismybag.whereismybag.didEnterRegion(whereismybag.java:91)`.  Is there other code not shown that may reassign a null value to this variable?

Comment: I can't seem to find anything that is causing this. If I remove `android:name=".whereismybag"`, the app starts to work fine, without the background scanning. Also, it sometimes is able to work for a bit before crashing, but it will crash regardless of what activity it is currently in. @davidgyoung

Comment: Strange.  I do not see how that variable can become null.  You could reinitialize it in that method with `beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);` but you should not have to.

Comment: One other thing you might try is testing with the 2.10 or 2.9 version of the library and see if you have the same problem.  If not, this might indicate it is a change introduce in the 2.11-beta

Answer (score 0):

From the logcat it show the error `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

> 06-12 11:20:46.335 26716-26729/com.example.utsav.whereismybag
>   W/Binder: Binder call failed.
>                                                                       java.lang.SecurityException: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or
>   ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
>                                                                           at
>   android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.startScan(IBluetoothGatt.java:678)
>                                                                           at
>   android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper.onClientRegistered(BluetoothLeScanner.java:367)
>                                                                           at
>   android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:56)
>                                                                           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:580)

In order to get the permission you have to use below code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 


if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     // {beacon code}
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION }, 
      TAG_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
}

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case TAG_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION: {
                if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // {beacon code}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think I can request for permissions as the background code is not in an activity. It is a class. I am asking for permissions in main and all other activities.
My problem is that if I include this background scanning code in the app, it makes the foreground process crash. Otherwise, the foreground process works fine without the background scanning included.